# Riverpod State management UI updating paradox -- unpredicatable functioning

Tags: memory-management, state, riverpod

Using Statenotifier to keep state of products addition and deletion from a shopping cart works differently for when the product is selected/deselected as favorites. In the latter case of wishlist, the UI updates immediately while for adding cart items, UI updates only upon hot reload or screen view swapping. The paradox is that similar codebase (wishList controller and cart controller) is used for both options in the same class (popular_products.dart).

Popular_products.dart (relevant sections):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productAttribute =
        ref.watch(productControllerProvider.notifier).getById(id);
    final cartProvider = ref.watch(cartControllerProvider.notifier);
    final wishListProvider = ref.watch(wishListControllerProvider.notifier);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
```

...(the favorite section works as designed with UI updating immediately.

```
 child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      ref
                          .read(wishListControllerProvider.notifier)
                          .addOrRemoveFromWishList(
                            id,
                            imageUrl,
                            price,
                            title,
                          );
                    },
                    icon: wishListProvider.wishlistList
                            .containsKey(productAttribute.id)
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                        : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                  ),
```

... the section for adding item to cart. This only works after hot reload rather than as it obtains in favorite action above; even with similar code.

```
InkWell(
                      onTap:
                          cartProvider.cartList.containsKey(productAttribute.id)
                              ? () {
                                  BotToast.showText(
                                    text:
                                        "Item already in cart. Change its quantity from your shopping cart. ",
                                    contentColor: Colors.red,
                                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    clickClose: true,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                              : () {
                                  cartProvider.addToCart(
                                    productAttribute.id,
                                    productAttribute.imageUrl,
                                    productAttribute.price,
                                    productAttribute.title,
                                  );
                                  BotToast.showText(
                                    text:
                                        "Item added successfully. You can increase or decrease its quantity from your cart.",
                                    contentColor: Colors.black,
                                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    clickClose: true,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                      child:
                          cartProvider.cartList.containsKey(productAttribute.id)
                              ? const Icon(
                                  Icons.check,
                                  size: 20,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )
                              : const Icon(
                                  Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                                  size: 20,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                ],
```

cart_controller:

```
final cartControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CartListNotifier, List<Cart>>(
  (ref) => CartListNotifier(),
);

class CartListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Cart>> {
  final Map<String, Cart> _cartList = {};

  Map<String, Cart> get cartList => _cartList;

  CartListNotifier() : super([]);

  double get totalAmount {
    double total = 0.0;
    _cartList.forEach((key, value) {
      total += value.quantity * value.price;
    });
    return total;
  }

  void addToCart(
    String pId,
    String imageUrl,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_cartList.containsKey(pId)) {
      updateCart(pId);
    } else {
      state = [
        ...state,
        _cartList.putIfAbsent(
          pId,
          () => Cart(
            cartId: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            title: title,
            price: price,
            quantity: 1,
          ),
        )
      ];
    }
  }

  updateCart(String pId) {
    return state = [
      _cartList.update(
        pId,
        (value) => Cart(
          cartId: value.cartId,
          imageUrl: value.imageUrl,
          title: value.title,
          price: value.price,
          quantity: value.quantity + 1,
        ),
      )
    ];
  }

  void decrementItemQty(
    String pId,
    String imageUrl,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_cartList.containsKey(pId)) {
      state = [
        // ...state,
        _cartList.update(
          pId,
          (value) => Cart(
            cartId: value.cartId,
            imageUrl: value.imageUrl,
            title: value.title,
            price: value.price,
            quantity: value.quantity - 1,
          ),
        )
      ];
    }
  }
```

wishlist_controller:

```
final wishListControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<WishListNotifier, List<WishList>>(
  (ref) => WishListNotifier(),
);

class WishListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<WishList>> {
  final Map<String, WishList> _wishlistList = {};

  Map<String, WishList> get wishlistList => _wishlistList;

  WishListNotifier() : super([]);
  void addOrRemoveFromWishList(
    String pId,
    String imageUrl,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_wishlistList.containsKey(pId)) {
      state = [removeItem(pId)];
    } else {
      state = [
        ...state,
        _wishlistList.putIfAbsent(
          pId,
          () => WishList(
            cartId: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            title: title,
            price: price,
          ),
        )
      ];
    }
  }

  removeItem(String pId) {
    return _wishlistList.remove(pId);
  }

  void deleteCart() {
    _wishlistList.clear();
  }
}
```

... the big paradox though is that the same code works as intended on product details screen for adding item to the cart but not for popular products. Here's the code for the ProductDetailsScreen.dart:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productAttribute =
        ref.watch(productControllerProvider.notifier).getById(productId);
    final cartProvider = ref.watch(cartControllerProvider.notifier);
    final wishlistProvider = ref.watch(wishListControllerProvider.notifier);

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            height: 50,
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed:
                    cartProvider.cartList.containsKey(productAttribute.id)
                        ? () {
                            BotToast.showText(
                              text:
                                  "Item already in cart. Change its quantity from your shopping cart.",
                              contentColor: Colors.red,
                              duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              clickClose: true,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        : () {
                            cartProvider.addToCart(
                              productId,
                              product.imageUrl,
                              product.price,
                              product.title,
                            );
                            BotToast.showText(
                                text:
                                    "Item added successfully. You can increase or decrease its quantity from your cart.",
                                contentColor: Colors.black,
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                clickClose: true,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ));
                          },
                child: cartProvider.cartList.containsKey(productAttribute.id)
                    ? const Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        size: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                    : const Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                        size: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
          ),
        ),
```

[image: You can see the item is favored but not showing that it is added . It would show when I hot reload or changing screen.]

[image: Cart and favorite reflected immediately without need to manually refresh UI from the same codebase]

Comment: You are using StateNotifier incorrectly. Consider reading the docs about it which should explain what you did wrong https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider

Comment: Remi, I have read the docs and the implementation is from my understanding of what I read. I basically used the ToDo sample code to implement the wishlist and cart provider codes almost to a t. I would greatly appreciate it if you can simply point out what I am doing wrong even after adapting the example in the doc I am not by any means asking for a handout but you as the author of this state management tool, you know where I am missing it and can help create another informed and knowledgable user of your tool. I have poured over the doc and other examples online but no luck. Thanks partner

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that you are using StateNotifier like a ChangeNotifier, but that's incorrect. You should not have state within the StateNotifier. Instead all your state should be within that `state` property. So you're have to remove the `_wishlistList` and `get wishlistList` and instead use a separate class, like showcased in the doc

Comment: I have decided to switch to ChangeNotifier entirely since that's more understandable to me coming from Provider. Now my cart and wishlist providers work as expected.except for cartscreen UI not updating when item quantity is changed or an item is deleted. I will open another topic to allow me post the new code and issue. Thanks for your anticipated assistance.